# Why is traceback linear in running time?

Tags: algorithm, bioinformatics

I implemented global alignment using linear gap cost. I understand that the running time for filling the matrix is O(mn) but what I don't get is the running time of the traceback.
Here is the pseudocode:
[image]

I can see that running time for traceback is O(n) because we are iterating through just one loop. But can someone give me a good explanation for this?

Comment: How are `i` and `j` initialized?

Comment: i is the length of one sequence and j is the length of the other sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppsed that `i` is initialized with `m` and `j` is initialized with `n`, the termination condition is that either `i` or `j` reaches zero. In either iteration of the loop, we decrease `i` or `j` or both; computationally, each of the cases incurs a constant cost. After at least `max{m,n}` steps the loop terminates. As probably the input size is `m*n`, namely the dimensions of a matrix,

```
max{m,n} <= m*n
```

holds, which results in a linear running time.